# When naming a keyboard, key, should the key's name be capitalized?

Tags: grammaticality, capitalization

I recently received some feedback about an error message on one of our internal applications.  When a user submits invalid input, we send a message that looks something like this:

> "Display Name" is required, must be less than 64 characters and must
>   only include alphanumeric characters, dashes and spaces.

The feedback I received was that "spaces" should be capitalized since it's the name of a key on the keyboard.  I disagree, however.  I feel like it should remain lowercase.  Can anyone help me understand the correct usage in this scenario?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're not describing a keyboard key, you're describing a graphic character.  It could just as easily be pasted in as typed.  (And if you capitalize "spaces" you should capitalize "dashes" as well, and &deity knows what you should do with "alphanumeric characters".)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about domain-specific rather than general English requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, in that scenario "spaces" should be lowercase. Unless it's a proper noun or at the start of the sentence, there is nothing that dictates the word "space" should be capitalized.

Keep in mind that in that sentence, it is referring to the physical "space" character rather than the space key on your keyboard like your question suggests. This makes little difference, as it should be lowercase either way. A keyboard character should only be capitalized if you're trying to convey information about a capitalized version of the character itself, which does not matter with the space key.